# Collision between a ball and a rectangle in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make the classic arcade game Arkanoid, but I am having problems with the collision between the ball and the bricks. Currently I am just using the classic collision (like in Pong):

```
def colision(self, objetivo):
    if self.rect.colliderect(objetivo.rect):
        self.speed[1] = -self.speed[1]

def colision2(self, objetivo):
    if self.rect.colliderect(objetivo.rect):
        self.speed[0] = -self.speed[0]
```

The problem I have is that when the ball hits different parts of the brick, sometimes it bounces the wrong way, and ends up "eating" more than a brick. I use 2 different types of collision because I added borders and I'm making it bounce with them too, but I don't know how to make the program realise which side of the brick is hit, and use `colision1` or `colision2` depending on the side.

Comment: Just add an identifier to the sides of the brick, then check if the collision was vertical or horizontal. Alternatively if you implement a proper 2D collision model, you don't need to care about the direction of the collision.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how to add identifier and check? And also, hoy can i make  a proper 2D collision model?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using/drawing a circular ball?  If so, the problem is probably because your using colliderect. When the ball comes near a brick the bounding box is colliding in a slightly different spot than it appears. Try using sprites and collide_circle.

Comment: I am using an image of the circular ball. But yes, im using colliderect. The thing is, i dont know how to use collide circle because the collision is between a circle and rectangles. Can you show me an example?

Comment: I would first run the program using a square sprite instead of a circle to verify it's the bounding box causing the problem. If confirmed, and you want pixel-perfect collision you can create a mask for all the sprites and use sprite.collide_mask(). Another option is to continue using rectangular collision but upon every collision use geometry to measure the distance from the center of the ball to the corner of the brick. This will tell you if the ball is touching the brick or it was just the corner of the bounding box that collided.